# Rails group_by associations displaying image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Player` model which `belongs_to` `Team` model by a foreign key named `teamId`.

I have a `group_by` method which groups players by `teamId` and lists them.

I want to first show an image (team logo), then loop my players, but unsure of how to do this.

So far i get an error stating:

```
undefined method `team' for 3(teamID):Fixnum
```

Controller

```
@players = Player.joins(:team).order('teams.name ASC').order('last_name ASC').group_by { |m| m.team.teamId }
```

View

```
<div class="container">
    <% @players.each do |club, player| %>
    <div class="row team">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <%= image_tag club.team.image %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">
            <% player.each do |p| %>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p><%= link_to p.name, player_path(p) %></p>
            </div>
            <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by team instead of grouping by team id

```
@players = Player.joins(:team).order('teams.name ASC').order('last_name ASC').group_by { |m| m.team }
```